# Is there a 'standard' read/write lock implementation for ruby?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, concurrency, locking

Does anyone know of an existing ruby implementation of a read/write lock - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers-writer_lock?

Preferably this would be in a popular library or some other implementation that's been used by enough people that it's fairly bulletproof at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a standard one to my knowledge, but they aren't terribly hard to write.  Failing that, [this guy](http://blog.jonahb.com/?p=10) has already written one.  It looks right and he's provided tests.

Answer (score 1):

The link in Jonas' blog is now broken, but I have built and tested another implementation, and anybody who wants to use it is welcome to:

https://github.com/alexdowad/showcase/blob/master/ruby-threads/read_write_lock.rb

Comment: Please note that you must first install the excellent "atomic" gem, from Charles Nutter and MeNTaLGuY!

Answer (score 0):

Within [`concurrent-ruby`](https://github.com/ruby-concurrency/concurrent-ruby) gem you find [`Concurrent::ReadWriteLock`](https://ruby-concurrency.github.io/concurrent-ruby/Concurrent/ReadWriteLock.html) and [`Concurrent::ReentrantReadWriteLock`](http://ruby-concurrency.github.io/concurrent-ruby/Concurrent/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html).

```
lock = Concurrent::ReadWriteLock.new
lock.with_read_lock  { data.retrieve }
lock.with_write_lock { data.modify! }
```